# Optional param in VXML subdialog

Tags: vxml

For our product we have to use a VXML subdialog to another external file, but this given subdialog have less var elements than the param elements we are sending.

Here is an example

```
<subdialog ...>
<param name="Param1" expr="'1'"/>
<param name="Param2" expr="'2'"/>
...
</subdialog>
```

In the caller, and

```
<form ...>
<var name="Param1"/>
...
</form>
```

Is there a way to declare a param as optional in a subdialog ?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer to myself, sadly there is no possibility you can pass more parameters to a subdialog than it expects.

Thus, we have to pass the exact same amount of parameters as the numbers of variables that are declared in the form.

Answer (score 0):

The W3C recommendation doesn't say anything about an optional param. What it says is:

- name: The name to be associated with this parameter when the object or subdialog is invoked.
- expr: An expression that computes the value associated with name.
- value: Associates a literal string value with name.
- valuetype: One of data or ref, by default data; used to indicate to an object if the value associated with name is data or a URI (ref). This is not used for  since values are always data.
- type: The media type of the result provided by a URI if the valuetype is ref; only relevant for uses of  in .

However, if you're sending more parameters than what you're going to use in your subdialog, you won't have any problems. Those params which aren't used would just get lost in the subdialog context.

Comment: That depends on how the VXML code is produced.  If it is handwritten then that's ok but but WIC Producer Studio generated code throws an error when you pass data that can't be accepted.  And Genesys Composer generated code does too I think.